# Can not merge (join) in excel

Tags: excel, merge

I have Sheet1 and Sheet2:

Sheet1:

```
KEY LABEL TRANSLATION

A   12    
B   23    bb
C   54    
D   77    
E   32    ee
F   67    
G   89    gg
H   33    hh
```

Sheet2:

```
Let LABEL TRANSLATION

C   12    cc
D   77    dd
F   67    ff
A   12    aa
```

---

What I want to do is: If "A" in Sheet1 == "A" in Sheet2, put "aa" in column TRANSLATION in Sheet1

---

Desired output:

Sheet1:

```
KEY LABEL TRANSLATION

A   12    aa
B   23    bb
C   54    cc
D   77    dd
E   32    ee
F   67    ff
G   89    gg
H   33    hh
```

---

I know it is not hard, but I am stuck. I have tried vlookup but failing

Comment: Should I run this code in SHeet 1 or 2?

Comment: For my solution you need to run it in sheet1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!$A$2:$C$5, 1, FALSE)=A2,IF(VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!$B$2:$C$5, 1, FALSE)=B2,VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!$A$2:$C$5, 3, FALSE),""),"")
```

I tried it and It works fine you can drag it to sheet 1 empty cells.

**Note:** you can control what to do if the values are not equivalent, instead of `""` you can put whatever you want.

**Note:** I changed the sheets names (Order) {Inside Image} in my example but I modified the query for you so **you can just use it without any modification.**

[image]

Comment: SHould I run it in Sheet1 or 2?

Comment: you should run it in sheet1 Cell C2

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have the values starting from cell A1 in the Sheet1 and values starting from the cell A1 in the Sheet2, you need a 4th column. You can't do this operation using just 3 columns, you need to add a new column in which you have:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A1;Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4;1;FALSE)=A1;LOWER(A1)&LOWER(A1));C1)
```

[image: VLookup example]

Comment: 1. semicolon gives me error
2. =IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$223,1,FALSE)=Sheet1!A1,LOWER(Sheet1!A1)&LOWER(Sheet1!A1)),Sheet1!C1).  - gives me 0 everywhere